# SELECT from a bulk collection

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, bulk-collect

Is it possible to select from a bulk collection?

Something along these lines:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR customer_cur IS
    SELECT CustomerId,
          CustomerName
    FROM   Customers
    WHERE  CustomerAreaCode = '576';

  TYPE customer_table IS TABLE OF customer_cur%ROWTYPE;
  my_customers  customer_table; 
BEGIN

  OPEN customer_cur;

  FETCH customer_cur
  BULK COLLECT INTO my_customers;

  -- This is what I would like to do
  SELECT CustomerName
    FROM my_customers
   WHERE CustomerId IN (1, 2, 3); 

END;
```

I don't seem to be able to select from `the my_customers` table.

Comment: You can't select from a PL/SQL collection; can you declare your types outside the procedure? You said you want to use the results, but how - can you just iterate over the collection, rather than try to select directly from it?

Comment: The actual query for the cursor includes a calculated column.  Based on the value of this calculation, I want to use some data from that collection and union with other tables (as a `SYS_REFCURSOR`).  If there's a way to "build" the cursor via iteration, that's a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Declare yourself schema-level types as follows:

```
create or replace rec_customer_cur
as
object (
    customerid       integer, -- change to the actual type of customers.customerid
    customername     varchar2(100) -- change to the actual type of customers.customername
);
/

create or replace type customer_table
as
table of rec_customer_cur;
/
```

Then, in your PLSQL code, you can declare

```
CURSOR customer_cur IS
SELECT new rec_customer_cur(CustomerId, CustomerName)
FROM   Customers
WHERE  CustomerAreaCode = '576';
```

... and then use ...

```
SELECT CustomerName
INTO whatever
FROM table(my_customers)
WHERE CustomerId IN (1, 2, 3);
```

This is because schema-level types **can** be used in SQL context.

Comment: You'd need to change the cursor to return the object type into the collection as well though; `SELECT rec_customer_cur(CustomerId, CustomerName) FROM ...`. Otherwise you'd hit PLS-00386.

Comment: @AlexPoole - you Yada Yada'ed over the best part. :) Is this in a cursor declaration (later using `FETCH mycursor BULK COLLECT INTO my_customer_table`), or do you need to do a `SELECT rec_customer_cur(..) BULK COLLECT....` statement?

Comment: I modified my answer according to @AlexPoole's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also display the dataset returned by the `select`, then just use a `REF CURSOR` as an `OUT` parameter.

The `SELECT ...FROM TABLE` is a `SQL` statement, which needs a `STATIC TABLE NAME`, as a `database object`. It throws an error since the collection name is not actually a database table as an object.

To return the dataset, use `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `OUT` parameter.

`open cur as select....`

Comment: The above is actually a simplified example.  I want to use the results of the bulk collection within the procedure to do some further processing.  Later, I will return a SYS_REFCURSOR based on that processing.